# Passing data from Ajax to controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a viewModel

```
public class School
{
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }
    public int BuildingId { get; set; }
    public int FloorId { get; set; }
    public int PlannedBy { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<HeadCountPerRoom> HeadCountPerRoom{ get; set; }
}
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
public JsonResult SaveHeadCount(IEnumerable<School>schoolViewModel,int action)
{
    // my code
}
```

I have written the javascript model and ajax:

```
function myfuncton() {
    var HeadCountPerRoom=[];
    var MasterEntry=[];
    HeadCountPerRoom.push({
        Month: month,
        Year: year,
        HeadCountId: seatCountID,
        SeatCount: SeatCount,
    });
    masterEntry= JSON.stringify({
        schoolViewModel:{ 
        SchoolId: SchoolId,
        BuildingId: BuildingId,
        FloorId: FloorId,
        PlannedBy: PlannedBy,
        HeadCountPerRoom: HeadCountPerRoom
    },
    action:3
});

 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: "../myController/SaveHeadCount",
    data: masterEntry,
    success: function (data) {
        //code.
    }
})
```

In the controller I am getting `null` in the `schoolViewModel` parameter and for the action parameter I am getting the value.  Why I am getting `null`?

Comment: your `masterEntry= JSON.stringify({
               schoolViewModel:{ 
                SchoolId: SchoolId,
                BuildingId: BuildingId,
                FloorId: FloorId,
                PlannedBy: PlannedBy,
                HeadCountPerRoom: HeadCountPerRoom
            },
             action:3
            )};` isnt valid is that a typo while typing in here ? the closing braces arent correct. they should be `})` rather than `)}`?

Comment: verify your code before pasting here.

Comment: that's a typing mistake

Comment: you should fix it in your OP so that you don't get downvoted

Comment: fixed. thanks for notifying

Comment: @ElmerDantas Can you explain more clearly?

Comment: @ElmerDantas I need the first parameters to be of IEnumerable type as a list of records will be going and not a single record. Fora single record it works, but I need it to work for multiple records

Comment: Your script is creating and sending a single `School` object, not a collection of `School`. Change the POST method to `SaveHeadCount(School schoolViewModel, int action)` and it will be correctly bound.

Comment: @ArghaRay any updates?

Comment: @ElmerDantas. Your answer is the correct one.  Its fixed.  Thanks

Comment: I post as answer as it's not correct put answers on comments. You can accept later. Glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are expecting a list of school and you your JS you're passing only ONE object. You should pass your model on your JS as an array:

```
    schoolViewModel: [
                      { 
                        SchoolId: SchoolId, 
                        BuildingId: BuildingId, 
                        FloorId: FloorId, 
                        PlannedBy: PlannedBy, 
                        HeadCountPerRoom: HeadCountPerRoom
                       }
                      ]
```